# Borrar espacios de una cadena de texto despues de un caracter especifico

Tags: sql

Buen dia espero alguien pueda ayudarme lo que necesito es eliminar los espacios despues de un caracter especifico en una cadena de texto es para insertar varios datos en SQL y son gran cantidad de registros.

```
insert into usuario values  (   1095836036  ,   '   ANGELICA CASTENOS RANGUEL   '   ,   21  ,   '   Sin direccion', 3212830787  ,   '   Activo',    '   2019-04-30  '   ,   '   2019-05-30  '   ,   '   Plan Matutino   '   )

insert into usuario values  (   1007898580  ,   '   SERGIO GOMEZ    '   ,   16  ,   '   Sin direccion', 3138863158  ,   '   Activo',    '   2019-04-30  '   ,   '   2019-05-30  '   ,   '   Plan Básico Mensual '   )

insert into usuario values  (   63553917    ,   '   MONICA ARDILA ANAYA '   ,   35  ,   '   Sin direccion', 3168467588  ,   '   Activo',    '   2019-04-30  '   ,   '   2019-05-30  '   ,   '   Plan Básico Mensual '   )
```

Estuve buscando y encontré este link http://www.texto.kom.gt/removerespaciosextra.htm de gran utilidad que borra los espacios extra en todo el texto pero aun sigo teniendo problema porque despues de cada comilla simple (' ) sigue quedando un espacio. Asi queda todo el bloque despues de remover los espacios.

```
insert into usuario values ( 1095836036 , ' ANGELICA CASTENOS RANGUEL ' , 21 , ' Sin direccion', 3212830787 , ' Activo', ' 2019-04-30 ' , ' 2019-05-30 ' , ' Plan Matutino ' )

insert into usuario values ( 1007898580 , ' SERGIO GOMEZ ' , 16 , ' Sin direccion', 3138863158 , ' Activo', ' 2019-04-30 ' , ' 2019-05-30 ' , ' Plan Básico Mensual ' )

insert into usuario values ( 63553917 , ' MONICA ARDILA ANAYA ' , 35 , ' Sin direccion', 3168467588 , ' Activo', ' 2019-04-30 ' , ' 2019-05-30 ' , ' Plan Básico Mensual ' )
```

Comment: queres correr un script para acomodar el sql? o no hay problemas de insertar asi y luego updatear la base con un trim? por ejemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41e444e/1/1  ( 2 tablas iguales, a la segunda se le hace un update luego de insertar )

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto el trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la función TRIM() de SQL y listo, un ejemplo de uso en un SELECT

```
SELECT TRIM('    MI TEXTO    ') AS TrimmedString;
```

RESULT: "MI TEXTO"